# UWP Assembly Error after Update to VS1015.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

today I updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. When I wanted to do a `Rebuild`, I encountered the following Error:

[image]

It reads:

```
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[...].
```

(I removed the `PublicKeyToken`) and

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'
```

This does not make any sense to me and it prevents me from building the whole thing. Also a `Clean Solution` and a manual deletion of the `bin` and `obj` folders doesn't make the error go away.

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce the issue. After installing the new `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` to v5.2 and using Syncfusion in Reference this issue appeared. However I still have no idea on how to resolve it.

Comment: The problem appear as soon as i add syncfusion control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UWP meta-package 5.2 had couple of problems and was delisted the same (or the next) day. See [details](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e766a904-7346-4f76-bad2-852d3b301b0e/known-issue-version-52-of-microsoftnetcoreuniversalwindowsplatform-delisted-all?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues) how to work around the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same issue, even after upgrading to 5.2.2 of UWP.

You need to install the System.Collections.NonGeneric nuget package.

Comment: `System.Collections.NonGeneric` does not exist in nuget. Also I should not need to install it, as it should be provided by default (it was working in previous version, too)

Comment: @user3079834 you are wrong. Nuget package exist - https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.NonGeneric/

Comment: @Daniil shame on me, you are right. I must have been in the wrong channel, when searching for it. Because the first time I searched for it, I got *no results*.

Comment: This should be marked as solution. I dont have time to read the details about the problem. I just want the problem to be gone and move on.

Comment: Please mark this solution as answer, because it's straightforward and working perfectly!

Comment: No, this is not the answer.  Has nothing to do with the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading the reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` to `5.1.0` in your project.json.

Comment: We published an update, 5.2.2 which should now work for all cases using the latest packages/libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I had success in upgrading either to `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` version `5.2.3` or `5.3.3`

Answer (score 1):

You can check/confirm if the ability to Restore/ Check missing Nuget package is already enabled in Visual Studio?

Open Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> NuGet package manager -> General. Make sure that both the checkboxes for "Allow Nuget to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" are checked. Once they are, try to `Clean` then `Build` the Solution.

**`Or`**

you can installed Mirosoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package via the Package Manager Console:
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

After that everything will work correctly.
The references
 [reference1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b3b8c2b-8558-4f37-9103-60bfb87ad942/uwpunable-to-build-windows-universal-samples-with-rtm?forum=wpdevelop)
[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228562/xamarin-uwp-project-is-not-being-built-after-creating-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: The marked answer did it for me, it really was an issue with the version.