# Xamarin UWP project is not being built after creating in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 and I created Xamarin.Forms Portable project. After that I have tried to build solution.

But I got an error for UWP  project: `Error Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, in Visual Studio 2015`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Check build config manager uwp selected or not

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution was simple. I installed Mirosoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package via the Package Manager Console:
`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`

Comment: Had the same problem. Installing NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform into the UWP project did solve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Was indeed simple! Please [mark your post as answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).

Comment: Not working for me . . . it gets four packages and appears to still be executing, but no further packages actually download, and build still fails.

Comment: It didn't work for me from console, but when I selected UWP project in Solution Explorer and opened Manage NuGet Packages and then searched for this package and installed it, eventually everything worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the newest version of NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform installed and it still isn't working, make sure that you're using the newest nuget.

We had it working in Visual Studio, but failing in command line. The reason was that we were using old version of nuget.exe, and this caused our F# fake script to use msbuild 14 instead of 15.