# Warnings: Creating Cross-plaftorm Xamarin Blank App (Xamarin.Form portable) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Whenever I try to create a new project of the type mentioned above I get these 4 warnings:

**Pre-updating Nuget**

## 1

```
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   xamarinProj1.Droid
```

## 2

```
The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'xamarinProj1, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'xamarinProj1.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() xamarinProj1.Droid          Build
```

## 3

```
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.   xamarinProj1.UWP            Build
```

## 4

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'   xamarinProj1.UWP    c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\xamarinProj1\xamarinProj1\xamarinProj1.UWP\xamarinProj1.UWP.csproj      Build
```

**Post-Nuget:**

## 2

```
The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'xamarinProj1, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'xamarinProj1.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() xamarinProj1.Droid          Build
```

## 3

```
IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   xamarinProj1.Droid      1   IntelliSense    Active
```

## 5

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Debug" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Expressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Dynamic.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>    xamarinProj1.Droid          Build
```

Notice that even though it's a warning in the emulator I don't see that application running (the default one "Welcome to Xamarin" label). Also, when I click on error #5 it will reappear on the next build.

Things that I've tried to solve it:

1. I've updated the project Nuget package and installed the newest Forms , also I've tried to install all the updates in Nuget manager for that project and still the problem remains
2. I've reinstalled Visual Studio and Xamarin
3. I've installed various version of JDK and tried to change in tools-> options-> Xamarin-> Android the various JDK folders: x64: jdk1.8.0_102 , x86: jdk1.7.0_55,jdk1.7.0_79,jdk1.7.0_80, jdk1.8.0_101
   (notice that in your manual installation you suggest to install x86 and so i've tried that as well)
4. Installed the newest XHAM from Intel site.
5. Updated Android SDK and installed basically all tools (including platformer and so on) and all API 23 and API 24 content, and various extras that sounds good to have also installed the latest NDK
6. Change project minimum target to a much lower Android firmware version (14)
7. I've updated Xamarin via Visual Studio
8. Searched the net and even tried to reinstall Nuget package manager as one suggested

I must mention that the original installer kept freezing when I've reinstalled Xamarin (after uninstallation as I've mentioned before), and the installer kept failing so I've installed it according to the [manual installation guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/).

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? I am having these same exact problems and have tried so many things, my workstation ultimately ended up needing to be "refreshed" (had multiple BSODs)... I am going crazy trying to resolve these errors- so any help would be greatly appreciated! NOTE: I too am simply trying to deploy a Blank Xamarin.Forms App. Thanks

Comment: I didn't completely solved the problem but it did improve to a degree that I could do some of the stuff described in a xamarin lesson video series (but not all) , the thing that worked was to actually change the version in nuget to the beta(I checked the "include beta" and picked that version) also I've deleted some of the projects that are automatically added to it and left only the android one and the w8.1 one the rest simply won't work for me, i still get one warning but it does function with that warning, no suggestion I've tried ever vanished it completely(sadly) hope i remember correctly

Comment: Right on, I'll keep plugging away lol! I did find this site (http://motzcod.es/post/150380059392/preparing-machines-for-xamarin-cycle) that explains (in detail) how to install everything properly (in more detail than the official documentation). I'm following it right now, if their method fixes the issue, I will report back! Thanks again :)

Comment: One thing I did notice I was doing wrong is that I didn't sign into my Xamarin account and I was using the 32-bit JDK... Here's another good read I found today regarding this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613162.aspx#windows

Comment: And one more (sorry, trying to be helpful here lol): https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/visualstudio-2017-rc/

Comment: why sorry? this thread as far as I can understand isn't really solved, the whole point of it is to have a complete solution to this, though I need to check in vs2017 if it's still a problem

Comment: I was apologizing for the streak of comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing a cross platform app in visual studio then check if your common project  which is the one in which the code is shared for all other operating systems and os specific project's references that is the nuget packages do not overlap in such a way that there is ambiguity.
I faced the same problem and removing the common references solved my problem in no time.
The package that was common in my case was named 'Windows'.

you can check your solution explorer like this.
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Your picture isn't very sharp but the thing you outlined with red don't look the same. Could you explain it more?

Comment: oh dear.. That image actually depicts where to look for references in a project and what does it look like. I solved my problem by checking each of my operating system specific project's references and removing them if any of them is duplicate with the one in the core cross platform project. Remember if there is something common between android and windows project references for example then dont remove on of them but remove if it is common between core project and android for example

Comment: So you mean that the things in project(portable) references also exist in project(android references I should delete it?                Update: The things in references I have are:  .NET, xamarin.forms.core, xamarin.forms.platform and xamarin.forms.Xaml. But all the xamarin.forms are also in all my project references folder. So should I delete al of them?

Comment: not the xamarin ones try to find if there's something else common. The ones more closely related to non graphical implementations.

Comment: can u show a screenshot or something having the references?

Comment: I made my one question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077588/warnings-cross-plaftorm-xamarin-blank-app-xamarin-form-portable

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try:

1. Cleaning all projects in your solution
2. Manually deleting all **bin** & **obj** directories in your solution
3. Updating all NuGet packages (solution-wide) to the "latest stable" versions
4. Running `Update-Package –reinstall` in the **Package Manager Console** (and verifying that there are no warnings present on any references)

Additionally, I have encountered errors with **Xamarin.Forms** that required me to uninstall the **Xamarin.Forms** NuGet package from the Android project and then reinstalling the "latest stable" version of Xamarin.Forms (not the **Xamarin.Android.Support.*** packages- those will automatically install during the reinstallation of **Xamarin.Forms**).

Doing the above usually resolves these strange errors for me. I hope this helps-
 good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check/confirm if the ability to Restore/ Check missing Nuget package is already enabled in Visual Studio?

Open Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> NuGet package manager -> General. Make sure that both the checkboxes for "Allow Nuget to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" are checked. Once they are, try to `Clean` then `Build` the Solution.

**`Or`**

you can installed Mirosoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package via the Package Manager Console:
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

After that everything will work correctly.
The references
 [reference1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b3b8c2b-8558-4f37-9103-60bfb87ad942/uwpunable-to-build-windows-universal-samples-with-rtm?forum=wpdevelop)
[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228562/xamarin-uwp-project-is-not-being-built-after-creating-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that path to the my VS Solution directory was too long. I moved my solution to the root of D drive and it all went good.