# Type Universe Not solved in VS 2015 & System.Runtime.Dll Error

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I am just start learing Xamarin 
I am running just a single line program just ***Hello*** **Xamarin**

Whenever I run the project it throws the error

---

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  App4.UWP

---

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
>   'System.Runtime.dll'  App4.UWP    C:\Users\Muhammad U
>   Usman\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.UWP\App4.UWP.csproj

Comment: Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1251097f-47a7-45b0-bff5-b08616ae424e/type-universe-cannot-resolve-assembly-systemruntime?forum=wpf or https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68945/regarding-cross-platform-app-development help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin UWP project is not being built after creating in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228562/xamarin-uwp-project-is-not-being-built-after-creating-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create a Universal Windows App with Xamarin. There is some error in the project creation, some of the dependencies might be missing. Go to project properties and check the target framework. If the target framework is .NET CORE, install packages related to Universal Windows Platform (UWP). Otherwise, if the target framework is classic .NET use the below link to get started.
[Create UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal)